# No page Cache after installing realurl

Tags: typo3, realurl

- TYPO3 7.6.18
- realurl 2.2.1
- bootstrap package 7.1.0
  – no other extension
- no other Typoscript aside from bootstrap package
- localconfiguration and htaccess copied from a fresh installation with introduction package
- PHP 7.11

When i install realurl the caching system of TYPO3 does not work anymore. The table cf_cache_pages remains empty, the admin panel tells me that there is no cache and of course the pages are slow. When i deinstall realurl all works as expected: the table will be filled with entries and the pages are quick after first hit.

When i make a fresh installation with the introduction package and realurl all works ... I am lost.

Any ideas where i have to look for this problem?

(I tried 1.13.7 of realurl and it works. But this isnt really a solution, I think ... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two reasons:

- Something is wrong with your languages. If you define language with uid=1 but try to get a link with L=2, realurl will prevent the page from being cached. This is the only case when realurl prevents caching.
- You use `typolink.useCacheHash = 1` in your language selector. This forces a cHash in links even when it is not needed. TYPO3 sees that cHash, sees that it is not needed and prevents page from being cached. This is the most typical reason.

You can enable TS rendering in the admin panel. You will see there messages who prevented caching and why.

Comment: Hi Dimitry, thanks for your answer, i was able to fix the problem. But i dont understand it really ... In my installation ar only 2 languages defined, 0,1. And there never was a link to one page with L=2. But because i use bootstrap the Language-MenuProcessor was defined wrong: special.value = 0,1,2.

Comment: For all with the same problem: add this line to your setup:
page.10.dataProcessing.40.special.value = 0,1
(1,2 means your correct languages). It seems that realurl compares this entry with the language entries in the database and deactivates the complete caching system of TYPO3 when there is a mismatch.

Comment: A, one addition: after adding this line you have to truncate this both tables of realurl: tx_realurl_pathdata and tx_realurl_urldata because the wrong urls are already in the cache.